# Setting the color of a Kivy Svg

Tags: svg, kivy

I was under the impression that svg worked like a canvas instruction.
However, I am unable to get the svg to change color. Part of the code below is using the code provided in the sample at Kivy's github.

```
with self.canvas:
     Color(0.3833, 1.0, 0.0)
```

Entire Code

```
import sys
from glob import glob
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics.svg import Svg
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from random import randint
from kivy.graphics import *

Builder.load_string("""
<SvgWidget>:
    do_rotation: False
<FloatLayout>:
    id: svg_holder
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: (1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
""")


class SvgWidget(Scatter):

    def __init__(self, filename, **kwargs):
        super(SvgWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0.3833, 1.0, 0.0)
            svg = Svg(filename)
        self.size = svg.width, svg.height

    def remove(self):
        print('remove', self)


class SvgApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = FloatLayout()

        for i in range(6):

            svg = SvgWidget('star.svg', size_hint=(None, None))
            self.root.add_widget(svg)
            svg.scale = randint(1,4)
            svg.center = randint(0,Window.width), randint(0,Window.height)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SvgApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you asking for is possible since the Svg contains **Color** instructions itself, so it overrides yours... Maybe your code can use an overlay with opacity to make the desired effect

Comment: Thank you, can you please provide an example?